# Linear transformation, base change

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear operator A in standard basis has matrix:

```
               2 5 −3
               −1 2 1
               2 −3 2
```

Find its matrix in base f1 = (1, 1, 1), f2 = (1, 2, 3), f3 = (4, 3, 3)

How should I solve this? I have already heard two ways of solving this and I have my own way, but the results for none of them match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a formula using the change of basis matrix. Let $P$ be the matrix with the coordinates of $f_1, f_2, f_3$ as vector-columns. This matrix is invertible, and $A$ is the matrix of the operator in standard basis, its matrix in the new basis is
$$P^{-1}AP.$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer matches with one of my solutions, will use this. Correction: it doesn't match, but there is one similar: PAP-1.

Comment: But I am thinking this could be correct

Comment: If the change of basis matrix is defined as I do (new basis expressed in the old basis), the correct formula is the one I gave.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to compute the matrix 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\ b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\ b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
\begin{array}{lclclclclclclclclcl}
Af_1 &=& b_{11}f_1 &+& b_{21}f_2 &+& b_{31}f_3 \\
Af_2 &=& b_{12}f_1 &+& b_{22}f_2 &+& b_{32}f_3 \\
Af_3 &=& b_{13}f_1 &+& b_{23}f_2 &+& b_{33}f_3 
\end{array}
Putting 
$$
F=\begin{bmatrix} f_1&f_2&f_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives
$$
AF=FB
$$
It follows that $B=F^{-1}AF$. Hence
\begin{align*}
B
&= F^{-1}AF \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-3&9&-5\\-&-1&1\\1&-2&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2&5&-3\\-1&2&1\\2&-3&2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&4\\ 1&2&3\\ 1&3&3\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1&35&-22\\-1&-4&0\\ 1&-7&9\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}